# Python enclosing scope: at call point or at definition?

Tags: python, scope

This is an example of an enclosing scope (is it also called lexical scope?):

```py
def outer(a):
    def inner():
        return a
    return inner

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inner = outer(10)
    print(inner())
```

This code also works:

```py
def printer():
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 10
    printer()
```

My question is: Is the "enclosing scope" rule used in the second example? If so, is there any distinction between the 2 types of enclosing scope: at call point/runtime and at definition?

Edit: as @user2357112 pointed out, `x` is global. This one doesn't work:

```py
def printer():
    print(x)

def outer(func_print):
    x = 10
    func_print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    outer(printer)
```

What a rookie mistake...

Comment: That `x` is a global.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I'm so embarrassed.

Comment: as soon as you *assign* to a name inside a function it becomes local (and shadows the global name inside the function). if you wanted to change the global `x` in your last example you'd have to use `global x; x = 10`.

Comment: also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/4954037